# How to make a bank program using def functions, returns and if elif else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the program I wrote, but I can't make a bank program that uses `def` functions like `def withdrawl ( current_amount,  withdrawl_amount )`. and uses `if`,  `elif`, and `else` for the option list. Please help.

```
balance = 2000
rt = 0.01
years = 0

while True:
 print('===============================')
 print(' Welcome to STEVENS UNIVERSAL BANK ')

 print('Please Choose an Option')
 print('Option 1: Withdrawl')
 print('Option 2: Deposit')
 print('Option 3: Check_Balance')
 print('Option 4: Balance with Updated Interest')
 print('Option 5: Exit')
 print('===============================')

 option = int(input('Choose an Option:'))
 years = years + 1

 if option == 1:
  withdrawl = int(input('How much do you want to Withdrawl?:'))
  balance = balance - withdrawl
  print (' New Balance :', balance)
 elif option == 2:
  deposit = int(input('How much do you want to Deposit?:'))
  balance = balance + deposit
  print (' New Balance:', balance)
 elif option == 3:
  print('Balance:', balance)
 elif option == 4:
  balance = balance * ( 1 + ( 0.0001 * years ))
  print (' Updated Balance', balance)
 elif option == 5:
  print (' Thank you for using THE STEVENS UNIVERSAL BANK ')
  exit()
 else:
  print('Invalid Input')
```

Answer (score 2):

You *are* using `elif` and `else` already. It looks like you do understand, mathematically, how to process the withdrawal, as well.

The Python 3 docs explain the syntax of how to declare and call a function
in the section [**4.6. Defining Functions**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

```
def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    """Print a Fibonacci series up to n."""
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

# Now call the function we just defined:
fib(2000)
```